# Special characters ignored on Android

Tags: javascript, android, iis-7, iis-6, jquery-mobile

I have built a booking frontend for mobile plattforms in jQuery-mobile.
It all works well both in the browser and on the iPhone, on an **Android** phone however it completely ignores the swedish special characters **Å,Ä,Ö**. When these characters are pressed it does not even trigger th keyDown event. All other characters work including *¨^ etc.

The system is run on a IIS7 but it has also been tested on IIS6 with same result. I have tried to strip down all my code and just show the input box but the error is still there. It seems to work well on a apache server.

Does anyone have a clue what could cause this or a workaround for the situation?

> Just tested with other browsers on Android and all works, its only the built-in browser that has the problem

Answer (score 0):

I would look into setting the charset:

- http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_meta.asp
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1

Maybe:

- iso-8859-1
- utf-8

Comment: I have tried to change both the pages charset and the IIS charset to ISO-8859-1 from UTF-8. Still the same result.

It probably has something to do with the charset in combination with the android browser, although cant think of what more to try.

Comment: you could also try a HTML Entity: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp or http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp

Comment: how do you mean i should use the enitity? Characters show up nicely in the interface but the input does not react on special character inputs on android browser.

Comment: I have problems with polish special characters in output, also on Android's default browser only. I've managed to blame it on the server side and I suppose it requires me to set encoding in http headers, because Android sends heders declaring use of 2 encodings. I'll be debugging it today evening. Come back in 10 hours to see my results ;)

Answer (score 0):

My problems with encoding on android required me to define a `charset=utf8` header for a CGI fetched by AJAX. 
By definition AJAX was always utf-8 but it turns out to be misinterpreted to be ISO-something on android.

The site I called the AJAX from was also in utf8

Comment: I have tries to set charset=utf-8 in the aspx site which has not made any different, where should i also set the charset?

Comment: you need to send a HTTP header stating what the charset is along with the content-type

Comment: This explains it for multiple programming languages http://www.w3.org/International/O-HTTP-charset.en.php

Comment: This actually solved it, seems that android browser only reads the charset from the response header and ignores any specific tags in the html.

Comment: Correction problem not solved only worked one time on one Android phone the problem still exist. Tried to set the response headers to both UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1

Comment: This must be it - you have not declared a content type and/or charset somewhere.